# Find duplicate partial value as substring

Tags: excel

I have two columns A and B. Column B has only names and column A has some information and the name. How do I compare these two columns for duplicate names?
Eg value in Column a is" Transferred 48$ by Avinash Kirate"   and column B has only name ie" Avinash"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel Exact Word Matching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100969/excel-exact-word-matching)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SEARCH` (not case sensitive) and see it it returns a number. If found, it will return the position (e.g. a number); if not found, it returns an error (e.g. #VALUE!).

`=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&B2&" ", " "&A2&" "))`

This will resolve as TRUE if found and FALSE if not. By wrapping both the *find_text* and *within_text* in spaces, you get closer to not finding word within another word (e.g. *Vina* within *Avinash*) but punctuation is not accounted for.