# Search for specific word in VBA string

Tags: vba, excel

There is a code I am using to search for specific words in a VBA string. Currently I'm using **InSTR**:

```
tag1 = InStr(1, dish, keyword, vbTextCompare)
```

However the challenge is that the search is comparing strings and not words.
E.g. If I'm searching for "***egg***" as a keyword in a string - ***Eggplant Pizza***, it's returning a true value.

Ideally I would simply like to search if the word "***egg***" exists in a string. Is there a better function I can use?

Comment: `.Find`? Record a macro or search stackoverflow.

Comment: you know Google?!?! if you searc  "excel vba find exact word in string" the 3th result it's a possible way to solve your ploblem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100969/excel-exact-word-matching

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Regular Expressions to achieve this in VBA.

Looking specifically at the ^ and $ operators to force the full word match.

So in your case something like ^Egg$ as the pattern should do what you want.

See here for some good help on this:
[How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)

Comment: The answer above this one is not correct. I cannot comment under it. That will return 1, i.e. find the instance of Egg that the OP is trying to NOT find

Answer (score 0):

`InStr` is the way to go. For finding out how many times a string is present in a text, you can use this one-line code. Here I use your example.

```
Debug.Print UBound(Split("Eggplant Pizza", "Egg"))
```

To make the code case insensitive, you can put `Option Compare Text` on top of your code module.